# replace special characters within a block using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all < and > between [code] block. I DO NOT want to select and replace all content within [code] I just want to select < and > within that and then temporary replace it to another characters. do other replacement and then back them to < > within [code].

solution that I use:

```
replace(/<(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi,"&_lt_;"); 
replace(/>(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi,"&_gt_;"); 

DO OTHER REPLACEMENT/CUSTOMIZATION HERE 

replace(/&_lt_;/gi,"<"); 
replace(/&_gt_;/gi,">");
```

only problem is that if content between [code] contain character [ it do not work before that character in block. how can I fix this?

example that works:

```
<b>
[code]
<form action="nd.php" method="post">
<b>
<strong>
[/code]
<b>
```

example that do not works:

```
<b>
[code]
<form action="nd.php" method="post">
<b>
$_POST[
<strong>
[/code]
<b>
```

EDIT: please only provide simple regex replace solution. I can not use callback function for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted-answer for the linked question doesn't work for me for the "*example that works*". However, the other answer *does* - it also works for the "*example that does not work*" (there was a typo though).

Try the following regex:

```
/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|<[\s\S]*?>/g
```

In the `replace()` function, you would use:

```
.replace(/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|<[\s\S]*?>/g, '$1');
```

**EDIT**
If I understand correctly, your **end-goal** is to keep all of the content within `[code][/code]` the same - but be able to do replacements on all HTML tags that are *outside* of these tags (which may or may not mean to fully strip the characters)?

If this is the case, there is no need for a long list of regexes; The above regex can be used (with a slight modification) and it can cover many cases. Combine the regex/replace with a callback function to handle your extra replacements:

```
var replaceCallback = function(match) {
    // if the match's first characters are '[code]', we have a '[code][/code]' block
    if (match.substring(0, 6) == '[code]') {
        // do any special replacements on this block; by default, return it untouched
        return match;
    }
    // the match you now have is an HTML tag; it can be `<tag>` or `</tag>`
    // do any special replacements; by default, return an empty string
    return '';
}

str = str.replace(/(\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\])|(<[\s\S]*?>)/g, replaceCallback);
```

The one regex modification was to add a group around the html-tag section (the second part of the regex). This will allow it to be passed to the callback function.

**UPDATE** (`[code]` isn't literal)
Per a comment, I've realized that the tag `[code]` isn't literal - you want to cover all BBCode style tags. This is just-as-easy as the above example (even easier in the callback). Instead of the word `code` in the regex, you can use `[a-z]+` to cover all alphabetical characters. Then, inside the callback you can just check the *very first* character; if it's a `[`, you're in a code block - otherwise you have an HTML tag that's outside a code block:

```
var replaceCallback = function(match) {
    // if the match's first character is '[', we have a '[code][/code]' block
    if (match.substring(0, 1) == '[') {
        // do any special replacements on this block; by default, return it untouched
        return match;
    }
    // the match you now have is an HTML tag; it can be `<tag>` or `</tag>`
    // do any special replacements; by default, return an empty string
    return '';
}

str = str.replace(/(\[[a-z]+\][\s\S]*?\[\/[a-z]+\])|(<[\s\S]*?>)/gi, replaceCallback);
```

Also note that I added an `i` to the regex's options to ignore case (otherwise you'll need `[a-zA-Z]` to handle capital letters).

Comment: no this is not the solution this select all outside and inside the [code] for me.  correct answer was /<(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi that I found. /<(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi and then />(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi to replace < and > to another characters. please try /<(?=[^\[]*\[\/code\])/gi it should select < within [code] correctly. but if we have a [ it not works.

Comment: please note that I DO NOT want to select all contect within [code] I just want to select < and > within that and then temporary replace it to another characters. do other replacement and then back them to < > . hope understand

Comment: your suggestion about end-goal is totaly correct but I can not use callback for this problem. I just can use simple regex replace templates. it is not neccessary that do this within one replace command but can not use callback for this because sometimes we get full content from input to proccess and sometime we just get a part of it to proccess and can not detect when we have full and when we have partial content. also we may have multiply [code] blocks..

Comment: @m3hdi Yeah, I have no idea what you're talking about =P. A "callback" is no different than applying a huge list of regexes - it just gives you the ability to do them all at once instead of one at a time. The `/g` at the end of the regex - that allows the regex to apply to multiple blocks. I'm trying to help out, but you're making it difficult by not listening to reason.

Comment: callback is a function. a function need a human that code condition for it depend on input (if else endif things), but in my script I get what I should process and what to be replace with, from input. there is not human (me :D ) intract to see what is input and code a condition for it.. input maybe extend and condition may extend so can not write them in function.

Comment: Nope, still not following you. What you're saying is that to write a callback - you would have to write conditions. However, you have a long-list of regexes to handle... conditions? Long story short - move your replacement code into the callback where it has `return '';`. If you post examples of the replacement code, I can update my answer to show how/where if you need.

Comment: then I should changes lot of code engine :D sorry but I can just  use simple replace templates for this problem :( you can imagine as many as [things_here] and [/things_here] with any string maybe used. it is used for a WYSIWYG editor for bbcodes. you may look source code here:    https://github.com/eMosbat/eMosbat-TinyMCE-Integration-for-phpBB

Comment: So `[code]` is not literal? It could be `[b]` or `[img]`, etc? That's just as easy to code for. In the regex, you replace `code` with `[a-z]+` and just check for the leading `[` in the callback =]

Comment: not possible that way, we have many other BBCode conditions too. please only none-callback solution :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17558/discussion-between-newfurniturey-and-m3hdi)

Comment: I am going to change some engine code after several hours so I accept your solution :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's my edited answer. Sorry again.

```
str = str.replace(/(\[code\])(.*?)(\[\/code\])/gm,function(a,b,c,d) {
    return b + c.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') + d;
});
```

Comment: just simple replace templates please, callback will not accepted for this issue.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why I picked PHP. Updating my answer. Sorry again.